# CakePHP 3 - data association before saving

Tags: php, cakephp, save

I have got function in controller which looks like this:

```
//Create room
public function createRoom(){
    $room = $this->Rooms->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $room = $this->Rooms->patchEntity($room, $this->request->data);
        $user_field = $this->Rooms->Users->find()->where(['id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
        $room->users = [$user_field];
        $room->current = 1;
        $room->owner_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        Log::debug($room);
        if($this->Rooms->save($room)){
            $this->Flash->success('You have created a new room.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error('Error creating new room.');
        }
    }
    $games = $this->Rooms->Games->find('list', ['limit' => 200, 'keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'name']);
    $this->set(compact('room', 'games', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['room']);
}
```

Tables "Users" and "Rooms" are connected in association table. When I run add a new room and I let the user choose who is in the room through the form then it is beeing saved, but when I want to add the first user on my own via $room->users = [$user_field]; its not beeing saved. I'm logging $room object into the file and both objects are the same (after adding user through the form and after adding user through the code). Help me :(

Maybe I should use beforeSave() or afterSave() in model?

**SOLUTION**
I found a solution with **Code.Working** help.
Instead of adding

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
```

to the initializie() method i just put it in my createRoom() function.

Final working code looks like this:

```
//Create room
public function createRoom(){
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $room = $this->Rooms->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $room = $this->Rooms->patchEntity($room, $this->request->data);
        $user_field = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
        $room->users = [$user_field];
        $room->current = 1;
        $room->owner_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        Log::debug($room);
        if($this->Rooms->save($room)){
            $this->Flash->success('You have created a new room.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error('Error creating new room.');
        }
    }
    $games = $this->Rooms->Games->find('list', ['limit' => 200, 'keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'name']);
    $this->set(compact('room', 'games', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['room']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reduce the set of users to a specific one, the returning value of find() is always a Query Object: [Retrieving Data & Results Sets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html).

Try this instead to reduce the set of retrieved Users to the first one:

```
$user_field = $this->Rooms->Users->find()->where(['id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])->first();
```

Or better, if the 'id' column is your primary key:

```
// In the initialize() method
$this->loadModel('Users');

// And in the action:
$user_field = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. where i put your solution into my controller ive got the following error: Call to a member function user() on boolean. What should I do with this?

Comment: Did you load the Auth Plugin? It might help to save Auth in a variable and print_r() in the view.
Like $this->set('auth', $this->Auth);
In the View: print_r($auth);

Answer (score 0):

i guess this would help u :

http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Association.BelongsToMany.html#_link

with link you can link the user object to the rooms object easily and it is the more beautiful solution i think. Assuming u have set up associations properly ofc!

Good luck :)

Comment: what is strange i managed to "unlink" user afterwards, but i couldnt make "link" to work. ill spend some more time on this and ill try to find an answer. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think a different method from loading the Model inside your controller could be using the `dirty()` method.

In your case, you will insert `$rooms->dirty('users', true);` right after `Log::debug($room);` and comment the load model of the Users. This will signal the 'users' association of the 'rooms' as **dirty**, and therefore it will save it when `$this->Rooms->save($room)`  will be called.

Give it a try ;)